# Can't get the AT command to work, Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

> at 8:24am "c:\windows\system32\calc.exe"

I see see a new item in task scheduler

8:24am comes, it says running, calc.exe appears in task manager stays there but no window shows.

ADDED

strange things going on

```
C:\>at /interactive 7:36 calc
Invalid command.

The AT command schedules commands and programs to run on a computer at
a specified time and date. The Schedule service must be running to use
the AT command.

AT [\\computername] [ [id] [/DELETE] | /DELETE [/YES]]
AT [\\computername] time [/INTERACTIVE]
    [ /EVERY:date[,...] | /NEXT:date[,...]] "command"

\\computername     Specifies a remote computer. Commands are scheduled on the
                   local computer if this parameter is omitted.
id                 Is an identification number assigned to a scheduled
                   command.
/delete            Cancels a scheduled command. If id is omitted, all the
                   scheduled commands on the computer are canceled.
/yes               Used with cancel all jobs command when no further
                   confirmation is desired.
time               Specifies the time when command is to run.
/interactive       Allows the job to interact with the desktop of the user
                   who is logged on at the time the job runs.
/every:date[,...]  Runs the command on each specified day(s) of the week or
                   month. If date is omitted, the current day of the month
                   is assumed.
/next:date[,...]   Runs the specified command on the next occurrence of the
                   day (for example, next Thursday).  If date is omitted, the
                   current day of the month is assumed.
"command"          Is the Windows NT command, or batch program to be run.


C:\>
```

I just tried reversing it so /interactive afterwards

```
C:\>at 7:38 calc /interactive
Added a new job with job ID = 28
```

And Calc.exe still only came in the background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not use `at`. It's insecure** – all jobs are given `SYSTEM` privileges, which is even worse than Administrator.

Use [`schtasks`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596) instead:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Foo" /tr calc.exe /sc once /st 8:24
```

---

By default jobs run by `at` are executed in background. You can use [`at /interactive`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/at.mspx?mfr=true) to change this:

```
at 8:24 /interactive calc
```

Comment: I just added to my question 'cos trying the AT one, while I think your AT command worked once.. trying it now, failed.

Comment: @barlop: Ah, you must put `/interactive` after the time, as the help output shows. (I didn't have any Windows box nearby to test.)

Comment: I think /interactive has to go between the time and the command

Comment: right ok seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The calculator started up on a sort of "virtual" desktop. It's there, you just can't see it. This is entirely expected behavior for `at`+`gui`.

The same thing happens when you use MS Office interop with ASP or ASP.Net -- the entire program starts on a private desktop on the server that no one can see.